# 3.times each.do then add class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an problem styling my rails application. At the time im using bootstrap and my html should look like this:

```
  <div class="row-fluid">

  <div class="span4">
  <div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn">02301</button>
  <button class="btn">Operativer Eingriff</button>
  </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="span4">
  <div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn">02311</button>
  <button class="btn">Diabetischer Fuß</button>
  </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="span4">
  <div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn">30130</button>
  <button class="btn">Hyposensibilisierung</button>
  </div> 
  </div>

  </div>
  ...and so on...
```

But with my code in the view, the class "row-fluid" is added each Paragraph!

```
  <% @ebms.each do |ebm|%> 
  <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4">
   <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn"><%= ebm.number %></button>
    <button class="btn"><%= ebm.extra %></button>
   </div> 
  </div>
 </div>
 <% end %>
```

So how can i achieve that only after three entries an class "row fluid" is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
<% @ebms.each_slice(3) do |ebm_slice| %> 
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <% ebm_slice.each do |ebm|%> 
      <div class="span4">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn"><%= ebm.number %></button>
          <button class="btn"><%= ebm.extra %></button>
        </div> 
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to repeat

```
 <div class='row-fluid'>"
```

for each row.

Add it only once, and thanks to the "float: 'left'" style associated with the span4 class, the span4 divs will automatically return to the next line when they need to.